# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' on line 56

Tags: php, arrays, select, multidimensional-array, jq

```
$cm_json = exec('curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2" -H "Authorization: Token token="XXXXXXX" -X GET -G  "https://api.pagerduty.com/users/'.$user_id.'/contact_methods/" | jq '.contact_methods[] | select(.label == "Mobile") | .address'');
```

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' on line 56

Comment: `.contact_methods[]` what is that?

Comment: Welcome. Either `$contact_methods[]` or `contact_methods()`. It also looks like you're missing  `.'` somewhere after `contact_methods[]`

Comment: Its working well in bash but not in php

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a quote issue. Use baskslash before the single quote of the jq filter:

```
$cm_json = exec('curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2" -H "Authorization: Token token="XXXXXXX" -X GET -G  "https://api.pagerduty.com/users/'.$user_id.'/contact_methods/" | jq \'.contact_methods[] | select(.label == "Mobile") | .address\'');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It's working.

Comment: When the answer is "you have a quote issue", there is no need to answer. Just leave a comment under the question and flag/vote to close as Off-topic: Typo. This page will be quickly scrubbed from the site (as will any upvote points you receive) because this page is completely useless to researchers.See: [Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232).